# javafx image display using the HBox and the VBox from for loop

Tags: java, for-loop, javafx, imageview

I'm placing images inside hbox where the `HBox` located inside the `VBox`

```
FileInputStream seats_fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("seat.png");
Image seats_image = new Image(seats_fileInputStream,50,50,false,false);

ImageView[] seats = new ImageView[30];

for(int i = 0;i<30;i++){
    seats[i] = new ImageView(seats_image);
}

HBox seatsRaw_hbox[] = new HBox[5];
VBox seatsLine_vbox = new VBox();

for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    seatsRaw_hbox[i]= new HBox();
    for(int j=0;j<6;j++){
        seatsRaw_hbox[i].getChildren().addAll(seats[j]);             
    }

    seatsLine_vbox.getChildren().addAll(seatsRaw_hbox[i]);

} 

BorderPane Test = new BorderPane();
Test.setCenter(seatsLine_vbox);
```

in should display 6 images in each `HBox` where there is 5 `HBox`es it total and place them into the `VBox`. But I keep getting only one row where I should get 5 rows!!!

Image of the output:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit silly error. In the for loop I place j < 6 where j represent the image array index where it suppose to start from 0 all the way to 29 but instead it just use the first 6 and stop. I had to create another variable where it will start from 0 and goes all the way to 29. Therefore, these is the modified code:

```
int seatsCount = 0;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++){
    seatsRaw_hbox[i]= new HBox();
    for(int j=0;j<6;j++){       
        seatsRaw_hbox[i].getChildren().addAll(seats[seatsCount]);
        seatsCount++;
    }
    seatsLine_vbox.getChildren().add(seatsRaw_hbox[i]);

}
```